# Windows command prompt--find a folder that contain 2015 in its name

Tags: windows, search, cmd.exe

I was wondering if it is possible to use command prompt to manually locate a folder in the directory that contains "2015" in its name and then enter that folder.

This is what I got from `"for /f "delims=" %a in ('dir /s /b /a:d *2015*') do cd %a"`

`U:\BeaverGames\Mobile\Custom Street Racer\Builds\GooglePlay>cd U:\BeaverGames\Mobile\Custom Street Racer\Builds\GooglePlay\2015-01-20 (2.5.0 RCd)`

`U:\BeaverGames\Mobile\Custom Street Racer\Builds\GooglePlay\Archive\2015-01-05 (2.5.0)`

Is there a way to narrow it down so it does not show the "2015" folders in the archive folder? Is it possible to ignore the archive folder altogether and just display the 2015 folder in the `Googleplay` folder?

Comment: By Command Prompt do you mean manually or using a bat file. You can locate a folder name by using dir *2015* /s /a:D then you can browse to that folder by simply doing cd xxx\xxx\xxxxx

Comment: Sorry I mean Manually

Comment: There should be * round the 2015... David's answer below is perfect for a bat file.

Comment: `2015/01/22` is not a valid directory name (The following characters are not allowed:  \ / : * ? " < > |)

Comment: Please add the output from `dir /s /b /a:d` to your question

Comment: Answer updated to work for folders with a `space` in the name

Comment: Oh great thanks David that narrowed it down. Is there a way to narrow it down further? Main Question updated.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Nice one that done it your amazing! Thank you so much for your time David :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is it possible to use locate a subdirectory containing "2015" in its name and then enter that folder?

From the command line:

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('dir /s /b /a:d *2015*') do cd %a
```

In a batch file:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b /a:d *2015*') do cd %%a
```

---

#### How can I narrow it down so it doesn't show the "2015" folders in the archive folder?

If the `/s` is removed the subfolders will not be searched.

From the command line:

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('dir /b /a:d *2015*') do cd %a
```

In a batch file:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a:d *2015*') do cd %%a
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be working for me. Sorry I am completely new to this. This is what i am trying to do. so im currently in "z:\BeaverGames\Mobile\Custom\Builds\GooglePlay" now in that GooglePlay folder is a folder that contains "2015" in its name which is the folder I would like to go into.

Comment: It keeps coming out with "File not found"

Comment: That gave me a list of all the folders and sub folders in that directory

Comment: I have updated the question if it helps.

Comment: w:\BeaverGames\Mobile\Custom\Builds\GooglePlay for /f %a in ('dir /s /b /a:d *2015') do cd %a - this gave me file not found